# Is it possible to express constraint on the tagged value of an applied stereotype in UML/OCL?

Tags: uml, ocl

For example, let's consider the following UML diagram:
[image]

The model has to be valid only if for all of the instances of `Block1`, the instance of `Block1::unit_of_press` is the same instance of the tagged value `unit` of the actual type of `Block1::press`

Is it possible to express such a constraint in OCL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to access the tagged values of an applied stereotype. See [Finding All Elements with a Given Tag](https://wiki.eclipse.org/OCLSnippets#Finding_all_elements_with_a_given_tagged_value) as a starting point. From there you can assert what must be true about the tagged value.

In case that web page becomes unavailable, an example is:

```
self.allOwnedElements()
->select(e | e.getValue(e.getAppliedStereotype('Ecore::EAttribute'), 'isTransient') = true)
```

(Thanks to Rafael Chaves, Vladimir Orany, and Bjoern Sundin.)